# Is it possible to program/flash ESP8266MOD(07) With Arduino UNO

Tags: esp8266

i am new to ESp and yesterday i received my **ESP8266MOD**, i don't have FTDi connector with me right now(it's on the way).

**Is it possible to flash ESP with Arduino UNO?**

Regards,
Ben

Comment: yes you can. all you need is 5 wires. flip rx and tx and put gnd to rst on the uno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Take a look at [this detailed guide](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Arduino/ESP8266/Flashing/Flashing-With-an-Arduino.html).

The most important thing to keep in mind is that you have to connect from the ATmega16U2's perspective, so you have to swap RX and TX:
[image]

You'll probably want some buttons to facilitate the flashing process:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. You can use the Arduino Uno 's Rx and Tx lines, but maybe you will need to have a voltage divider resistor arrangement to step down the 5V UART lines from the Uno to the 3.3V needed by the ESP, otherwise you risk damaging the ESP.

The basic approach to flash a ESP is described by several web sources and instructables, such this one [Getting started with the ESP8266 ESP-12](http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-the-ESP8266-ESP-12/) (there is also one section how to flash with an Arduino Uno).